# What bends fabric of space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

I know that mass can bend fabric of space-time, which causes gravity by making an object curve around a planet or star but is there anything else that can bend it?

Other energy sources, forces anything?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to mass (energy), tension and pressure can also act as sources for gravity.  All the sources are encapsulated in an object called the energy momentum tensor as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)

Comment: more simple terms? so does this mean mass and also energy can bend space-time?

Comment: Yes energy, such as radiation, also acts as a gravitational source.