# Can Space-Time be Distorted by Anything Other Than Mass?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, mass, curvature, gravitational-waves

We know that mass distorts space-time. We also know that Einstein equated mass to energy. We believe that mass is energy and energy is mass.

Can space-time be distorted by anything other than mass? If energy can be transferred from point A to point B in space-time without the "delivery vehicle" of a moving body (mass), must space-time distort in order for that to be possible?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Well, energy curves spacetime, cf. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107808/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43251/50583

Comment: and this one... http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70993//

Comment: @ACuriousMind One of twistor59's comments in your reference greatly interests me.

Comment: This also seems to be a list-based question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What bends fabric of space-time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43251/)

Comment: The Einstein Field Equations, $G_{\mu\nu}=8 \pi T_{\mu \nu}$, has $T$ the stress-energy tensor, which describes the flow of energy and momentum through a volume of spacetime. So pressure "distorts spacetime" too, and so does anything else which changes the stress-energy tensor.

Comment: Radiation does move energy from one spatial region to another. Could be electromagnetic or gravitational waves. No body of mass needed, both of those have energy and no rest mass, or body. As they move they distort the spacetime.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a mechanism that can exploit space itself to transport matter energy from point A to point B. Kind of warp drive. I am not saying it is possible, but if it is possible, then yes, it would warp/distort space in a manner that would be different from the way "mere presence of mass/energy" curves the space.

So, yes, space has to be warped/distorted to make it possible, what you have described - i.e. transport mass/energy from point A to point B without "delivery vehicle" of a moving body (mass). But what is transported itself is moving mass/energy, but it would be goods container, not delivery vehicle.